# MongoDB pre-save hook - do not save on conditional

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to be able to save a RegUser (registered user) to the MongoDB RegUsers collection only IF the email domain provided exists in the Firm collection. I have a pre-save hook that validates the email domain but I do not know what command/function to call to cancel the save if the email domain does not exist. Is there a better way to accomplish this or what command should I call?

** registered-user.ts **:

```
regUserSchema.pre('save', async function(done) {
  const domain = this.email.split('@')[1];
  const exists = await Firm.findOne({ domain });
  if (exists) {
    done();
  } else {
    // WHAT TO DO HERE??
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to stop the continuation of the hooks and the actual update `mongoose` excepts you to [throw an error](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#error-handling), you might need to add error handling to your code depending on how it's written.

```
if (exists) {
    done();
} else {
    throw new Error('firm does not exist')
}
```